# What should be R1,R2 in order to get minimum current and let the circuit operate

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, resistance, current-limiting, fuses

I'm given a circuit in which there is a voltage source of 24V, a fuse of 2 Ohm and maximum current of 60mA.
we are asked what should be R1, R2 in order to let the circuit operate regularly with MINIMUM CURRENT.

we know that device 1 demand voltage of 9V and power intake of 45mW.
device 2 requires V=24V & P=480mW.

this is the first time i encounter a fuse, and after reading a lot i tried to build some equations about the total resistance and use V=IR on an equal circuit by using Thevenin theorem. I'm a little stuck and plus i lack 1 equation.

[image]

Comment: making all your text bold makes no sense – you can't put emphasis on your whole text without losing all the emphasis. So, I removed the bold formatting

Comment: Replace the fuse with a resistor. Replace each of the loads with a resistor. You know the currents and voltages in some of the branches so draw them in. There is a schematic editor button on the toolbar so you can show your work and we'll help where you get stuck. Please capitalise properly for legibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

I'm not just going to give you the answer to a homework problem.

However, start by finding the current each device will draw.  From that you can find the voltage drop across the fuse, and then the voltage at the right side of the fuse.

If you want most efficient, R2 needs to be infinite, so basically not there.  Given the voltage at the top of R1, the voltage device 1 needs at the bottom of R1, and the current the device needs thru R1, you can calculate R1.

Despite the above, I want to point out that this is a terrible way to make 9 V for device 1.  This circuit is relying on the device to always draw the specified current at 9 V.  In the real world, you'd use a 9 V regulator, like a 7809 for example.

Comment: Note that this problem does not have an exact answer since any voltage drop across the fuse will prevent device 2 from receiving 24 V.

Comment: @Charles: True.  That also begs the question as to whether device 2 will still draw the full 480 mW, or whether it should be considered resistive and therefore draw less.  Still, the voltage drop across the fuse is quite small, and the voltage to its right is still within what one could expect from a "24 V" supply without further details.

Comment: Thank you for you direction. that was quite educating.
I did as you guided me to, and found the currents on each device, thus was able to build KCL equations on the nodes.
afterwards I was able to notice that if R2 is infinite we get a minimal current of 25mA.
after comparing the voltages of R1+DEV1 to voltage of DEV2 (parallel) i get that R1 is 3000[Ohm] = (24-9)V/5mA
is that correct so far? if so i thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: @Avi: Yes, 3 kOhms for R1 with R2 open (infinite) looks right to me.  That ignores the very small voltage drop across the fuse.  That would be legitimate simplification in for a real world circuit.  It changes the ideal R1 by well less than its reasonable tolerance.  Of course in the real world we'd use a regulator instead of R1 and R2.